# Google Drive: Disable "Open with" our app from Google Drive dashboard

Tags: google-drive-api

We have a Google Drive integrated app (marqueed.com) that allows you to authenticate and upload your Google Drive images from inside our app.

However, we don't want Google Drive users to be able to open files ("Open with") our Marqueed app from the Google Drive dashboard: 
[image: Disable this]

We don't want our app to show up in the above screenshot, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application shows up in the Open With menu for those files whose MIME types or extensions are listed in the Drive SDK tab of the APIs Console: https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Just remove those values from both Default and Secondary MIME Types and Extensions and your application will not show up anymore.

For more details, check the documentation at https://developers.google.com/drive/register#setting_mime_types_and_extensions

Comment: Thanks Claudio! worked perfectly, I should've tried that before, but was worried it would break the Google Drive integration inside our app.